# VB.Net Threading suspending and resuming

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, resume, suspend

Okay so for school we need to make a threading program that suspends and resumes. It is supposed to count from 0 to 6 then back down to zero then back up again.

However instead of printing the values as it counts, it instead just prints the value of 1 a single time. The code is as follows:

```
Module Module1
Public A As System.Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf MethodA)
Public B As System.Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf MethodB)


Sub MethodA()
    Dim C As Integer
    C = 0
    C = C + 1
    If C = 6 Then
        B.Start()
        If A.ThreadState = Threading.ThreadState.Running Then
            A.Suspend()
        End If
    End If
    Console.Write(C)
End Sub

Sub MethodB()
    Dim C As Integer
    C = 6
    C = 6 - 1
    For C > 0
        Console.Write(C)
    Next

    If A.ThreadState = Threading.ThreadState.Suspended Then
        A.Resume()
    End If
End Sub

Sub Main()
    A.Start()
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it won't run"? Are you getting an error? If so, what error, and where?

Comment: Well for starters there's no loop in MethodA... and in MethodB, I'm assuming that should be For C = 6 to 0 Step -1, not For C > 0.

Comment: Thank you for answering me! Sorry i wasn't so clear. By it wont run I meant I couldn't get it to work. No errors it just as @charliefox2 said it outputted 1. I understand what I did wrong now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, I'm guessing what is happening is your console only outputs `1`, and then waits for the user to exit. See my comments below.

```
Sub MethodA()
    Dim C As Integer
    C = 0
    C = C + 1 'set C equal to 0 + 1
    If C = 6 Then 'C equals 1, not 6
        B.Start()
        If A.ThreadState = Threading.ThreadState.Running Then
            A.Suspend()
        End If
    End If
    Console.Write(C) 'Write C, which is 1
End Sub
```

Also, you have:

```
For C > 0
    Console.Write(C)
Next
```

But I'm pretty sure the proper syntax would be:

```
For C = 6 To 0 Step -1
    Console.Write(C)
Next
```

That should get you going again.

**Edit:** Basically exactly what @Capellan said in his comment.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. Yes you are correct all it outputs is 1. Now i see what i did wrong. Thank you so much for the help! :)

Comment: If my answer helped, please upvote it/mark it as correct. It's also customary to upvote things that helped, like @Capellan's comment.

Comment: I have up-voted and marked your answer as correct. However, I require 15 reputation points for it to change on public display. I have only recently started using this site so maybe that is why. Also, I don't see to have the option to Up-vote commments

Comment: It's just to the left of the comment, right above the flag. You may require a certain rep to do that though, I can't remember.

Comment: Yes i think it requires a certain rep because I can't seem to find a flag either.